# how to fix "OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, cmd, jupyter-notebook, thonny

I am trying to get along with pandas.
I am learning Python using Thonny as IDLE. I installed pandas using the pip command in my cmd. Somehow i couldnt import pandas method in my IDLE, therefore i added it as package through settings. 
Problem is: when I try running following code, i only get the error in jupyter notebook and my cmd, but not in the thonny IDLE.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("pokemon_data.csv")
print(df)

Out(Cmd):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pokemonData.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\__init_
_.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__
.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\__i
nit__.py", line 23, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.p
y", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 ist keine zulässige Win32-Anwendung

Out(jupyter notebook):
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-686db4b56d1d> in <module>
      1 
----> 2 import pandas as pd
      3 
      4 df = pd.read_csv("pokemon_data.csv")
      5 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     11 for dependency in hard_dependencies:
     12     try:
---> 13         __import__(dependency)
     14     except ImportError as e:
     15         missing_dependencies.append(dependency)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
--> 142     from . import core
    143     from .core import *
    144     from . import compat

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     21             # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
     22             # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
---> 23             WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     24             DLL_filenames.append(filename)
     25     if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    354 
    355         if handle is None:
--> 356             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    357         else:
    358             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 ist keine zulässige Win32-Anwendung
```

Comment: Are you able to launch this application not from python code but from command line ?

Comment: if I enter this code in command line, I directly get the error...seems like installation of the pandas library via pip install somehow didn't work...not sure what to try nex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing might have happened. VS code automatically searches for the `numpy` and other packages from predefined OS locations. You might be using the 32 bit version of `numpy` instead of a 64 bit version. To fix this, you can

- Uninstall `pandas` from all OS locations.
- Reinstall `pandas` if the problem persists

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure that you are not copy-pasting the same answer to multiple (old) questions, but rather mark the questions as duplicate (if they are).

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error message while importing pandas and numpy.

```
File "<ipython-input-2-844cb1137ef2>", line 1, in <module>
import  pandas as pd

File "E:\Anacond\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
__import__(dependency)

File "***C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
packages\numpy\__init__.py***", line 140, in <module>
from . import _distributor_init

File "***C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py***", line 26, in <module>
WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))

File "E:\Anacond\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I installed Anaconda in E:\Anacond\ but still it was referencing to ***C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy__init__.py***
I deleted the old Python Folder inside C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\
which resolved the issue.It seems like python was referencing to some old files
which caused the error.